# Left Ctrl + Shift switches my keyboard to Dvorak and I would like to stop it from changing

Tags: dvorak

Some time ago on XP I was considering switching to Dvorak and I found this little program on line, "click here" and from than on the left Ctrl + Shift switches me to Dvorak.  Well now it is just a hindrance and it followed me from XP to Windows 7.  I've been the 'normal' route going through the control panel but it shows there it has never been changed.  I'm not a programmer, I probably know just enough to get in trouble.  I suspect something in the registry got changed, but that is just a guess.  Can you at least tell me where to look.  I could probably delete a line or change some small thing in registry if I knew where to look but that is about the limit of what I know.  Thanks

Answer (score 130):

Since the last windows 10 update you can disable that functionality by opening windows settings and following these simple steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you are such a life saver, I could not find all the other options of any help, as windows have removed all those in the recent versions

Comment: For me, "Region & language" was just "Language", and you had to go to "Spelling, typing, & keyboard settings" on the right, then "Advanced keyboard settings" at the bottom (you might need to scroll)

Comment: I also managed to find the right place, but again it was slightly different to both of the accepted above examples. The quickest way I found in the end was simply to type "Advanced keyboard settings" in Start.  Then click "Input language hot keys" and go to "Advanced Key Settings" and switch any keyboard shortcuts off.

Comment: I disagree that the steps are "simple", but thanks nonetheless.

Comment: In Windows 11, it's Start Menu -> Type 'Settings' -> 'Time & language' -> Typing -> Advanced keyboard settings -> 'Input language hot keys' to get to the Text Services and Input Languages window as displayed in the answer above.

Comment: An easier way and will work in almost any windows version. Run this command in a CMD or RUN box: rundll32 Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL input.dll,,{C07337D3-DB2C-4D0B-9A93-B722A6C106E2}{HOTKEYS}

Answer (score 89):

I think this question is better suited to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), but I'll try to answer it for you.

There are literally thousands of registry entries related to language input and keyboard layout, so tackling that would be troublesome. Your best bet would be to try disabling this properly through the GUI.

For Windows 10 ([source](http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/change-key-sequence-in-windows-10.html)):

1. Click "Clock, Language, and Region" from the control panel
2. Click "Language"
3. Click "Advanced settings" in the right column

   - If you'd like to remove Dvorak as an option entirely, click "options" here and remove it under "Input method"
4. Under "Switching input methods", click "Change language bar hot keys"
5. Select "Between input languages" and click "Change Key Sequence"
6. Disable/change the keyboard shortcut as you'd like

For older versions of Windows, the process is similar:

1. Open the "Region and Language" panel from the control panel.
2. Click the "Keyboards and Languages" tab.
3. Click the "Change keyboards..." button.
4. Click the "Advanced Key Settings" tab.
5. For each item listed under "Action", click the "Change Key Sequence..." button and either clear the "Enable Key Sequence" checkbox, or select the "Not Assigned" radio buttons.

If you no longer want to have Dvorak has an option, back in the "Change keyboards..." panel, go to the "General" tab, select "United States-Dvorak" and click the "Remove" button.

Don't forget to apply the changes!

Comment: UPDATE:   on current version of Windows 10, the item from where you access the "change key sequence" (in the Advanced keyb settings" was renamed to "Language bar options"

Answer (score 44):

For `Windows 10 Pro, version 1809`, the settings seems to be at yet another place as mentioned above:

1. Open *Settings* App
2. Click *Devices*
3. Click *Typing* in the left column
4. Click *Advanced keyboard settings* at the bottom
5. Click *Language bar options*
6. Choose *Advanced Key Settings* tab in the popup
7. Select *Between input languages* and click *Change Key Sequence...*
8. Set both *Switch Input Language* and *Switch Keyboard Layout* to **Not Assigned**
9. Click *OK*

Comment: Thank you! 
Near perfect answer, only one silly little step could be added, between 6 and 7. Here you have to click "Input language hot keys".

Answer (score 6):

In Windows 10:

Type in the search bar of the start menu **Control Panel** -> Click **Language** -> Click **Advanced settings** -> Click **Change language bar hot keys** -> Click **Change Key Sequence**

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Windows 10 has moved things around since this post. It may be easiest to search Settings for "Advanced Keyboard Settings."

- Start > Settings > Region And Language
- Advanced Keyboard Settings on the right hand side
- Language Bar Options
- Advanced key settings
- Between Input languages
- Change Key Sequence... Not Assigned
- Ok (then Apply For Windows 10 )

Comment: Have you considered utilizing formatting or line breaks?

Comment: @kres0345, I've reformatted the answer per your suggestion. It didn't take much time, and I don't think it required much reputation.